# How to get multiple values of same variable in the function class from local.settings.json file?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

**Language Stack**: .NET 6 LTS

**IDE**: Visual Studio 2022 Community

**local.settings.json**:

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
      "toAddress": [
        {
          "mail1": "abs@gmail.com",
          "mail2": "xblade@hotmail.com",
          "mail3": "hornet2@honda.com"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

**Function Class**:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ArrayVarPoC
{
    public class Function1
    {

        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public Function1(IConfiguration config)
        {

            _config = config;

        }
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string[] toAddress = _config.GetValue<string[]>("toAddress");
            log.LogInformation($"[{toAddress.ToString}]");
            

            string responseMessage = "Hello Fish, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to get the single value of the variable defined in `local.settings.json` but not the array variable values.

I tried to get the array variable values defined the `local.settings.json` file to the function class but not sure how to write the code for it.

Could anyone help me how to get this?

Comment: What is the framework and version of your Azure Function?

Comment: .NET 6 LTS @Harshitha

Comment: Is your issue resolved or still having problem ?

Comment: Not resolved yet @Harshitha

Comment: Ok..Will work on it and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254669/discussion-between-harshitha-and-prasad).

Comment: This works only when the value is in string [format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTurg.png).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254680/discussion-between-harshitha-and-hari-krishna).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write in an array format to get the values.

```
"Arrayofitems": {
"conn1": "testconnectionString1",
"conn2": "testconnectionString2",
"toAddresses": [
  "Address1",
  "Address2",
  "Address3"
]
```

}

```
var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection($"Arrayofitems:toAddresses");
string[] values = section.Get<string[]>();
```

you will get the array values on the "values" variable.

[image]

Comment: I think I tried the same and mentioned in my question

Comment: "toAddress": [
          "abs@gmail.com",
         "xblade@hotmail.com",
         "hornet2@honda.com"
      ]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/MloFLJS.png - Not Working

Comment: I wrote the same code as you and pasted the screen shot.

Comment: Is that Azure Function or normal .net console app? I'm getting null in the variable as you can see this https://i.imgur.com/vG7kGZ0.png

Comment: Its a webapp, you can configure startup class in Function App as well, where you can read all values from json file, via EnvironmentVariable class.

Comment: Can't we read the `local.settings.json` values from the function class directly using `IConfiguration` because we already many values without using startup class and only thing/requirement is to get the array values from `local.settings.json`?

Comment: Let me try that, since we had database connection and other items, we had to setup a startup class and get the values.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to retrieve the Values with your given Configuration, even I got null values.

[image]

- Tried in multiple ways with `GetSection` and `GetValue`, but unable to retrieve the values in Array format.
- AFAIK, we can retrieve the values from configuration when the `Key-Values` are in String format.

Thanks @MuthuKumaranMurugaachari-MSFT for the explanation.
In addition to the answer from [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1334329/how-to-get-multiple-values-of-same-variable-in-the), check the below code which worked for me.

- Change the Configurations in the `local.settings.json` file as below.

***My `local.settings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "mail1": "abs@gmail.com",
    "mail2": "xblade@hotmail.com",
    "mail3": "hornet2@honda.com" 
  } 
}
```

***My `Function1.cs` file:***

```cs
 [FunctionName("ConfigValues")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");     
            var myconfig = new
            {
                mail1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mail1"),
                mail2 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mail2"),
                mail3 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mail3"),
            };
           
            return new OkObjectResult(myconfig);
          
        }
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]